# In Drupal 7, how can I can display sub-module items that are not expanded?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'd like a menu structure that is something like the following to be placed into a page's sidebar.

```
Insects
Animals
    Mammals
        Bears
        Whales
    Reptiles
        Snakes
```

I'd like it to be set up so that if a user is on the bears page, the animals and mammals menus will be expanded...but the user COULD click an arrow next to reptiles to have that menu expand, and see the snakes option. When I checked the $page['sidebar'] render array, however, child menu items that are not expanded are not even included in the array. So, if I am on bears, there is nothing below $page['sidebar'][whatever number reptiles is]

I thought about writing a module that builds this through the DB, but at that point I'd be pretty much re-writing and implementing the menu modulem since I'd need to also include the html output of this new data on the page. What's the best way to approach this?

Note: also posted this on Drupal's stack exchange, but that seems to get way less traffic.
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14619/displaying-all-sub-menu-items-even-when-not-expanded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following module combo should accomplish what you are looking for. We had the same goal for a site we just did.

- taxonomy_menu
- taxonomy_menu_trails

And if you decide you want the user to click the arrow and have the items expand:

- dhtml_menu

Sorry for not including links, SO said it was spam.